# how to add DKIM in Plesk?

Tags: dns, plesk

I am running Plesk Panel with Centos 7 and using the Postfix as a mail server. My concern is my emails are going to Gmail Spam. Gmail ask me to add the DKIM record since I am using the postfix with centos I am not able to find how can I add DKIM in plesk. Can any one guide me?

Answer (score 1):

To enable DKIM signing of outgoing email, go to Websites & Domains > Mail Settings of a domain, select the Use DKIM spam protection system to sign outgoing email messages checkbox and click OK.

Note: DKIM signing will function only for domains that use the Plesk DNS server.

If you have activated DKIM for a domain, Plesk adds the following two records to the DNS zone of the domain (example.com stands for your domain name):

default._domainkey.example.com - contains the public part of the generated key.
_ domainkey.example.com - contains the DKIM policy. You can edit this policy.